# Why isn't Blending Mode: Difference inverting colors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, shapes

I have one document that has rectangular shapes on top of a clipped rasterized image, and while changing the Blending Mode of the shape to Difference, the colors underneath get inverted. Although, I'm running into an issue. I have a second document that is a different size (generated by dragging a .jpg to open a new document with the .jpg), I copied the shapes from the first document to the second, and the invert effect from the blending mode no longer inverts... Not sure why this is happening. I would like to have the same effect across both documents, I'm just very unsure why I can't get the second document to have the same invert effect...

Thanks in advance. I can provide any documentation or screenshots if needed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm uncertain how anyone could answer this without examining the document. I will say that blending modes will act differently in CMYK documents than they do in RGB documents. Beyond that, there must be some variation in your files you aren't seeing.

Comment: I did originally change the RGB document to a CMYK. Although, I just added the document one elements to a new CMYK document, and moved the .jpg image for dimensions to that new CMYK document and adjusted the art board accordingly. Turns out, that fixed the issue. I knew it had something to do with the document, but was also unsure how to assess the issue. Your input helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No. Diference does not invert an image, it highlight the diference between pixels on top of it.

If you had that effect it is only by chance. It only works on white background.

[image]

Original image: https://pixabay.com/es/retrato-vista-de-noche-femenino-787520/

Errata. The last image should be titled "Blue Background"